# Making a hashcode function using recursion

Tags: c, recursion, hash

I initially had a problem with my arguments, but that was fixed. However now I get a seg fault error and am not sure how to fix it.

here's my code

```
int hash_code(const char* str){
 int len = strlen(str);
 char dst[len-1];
 if(len == 0 )
  return 0;
 else{
 strncpy(dst, str, (len - 1));
 return (hash_code(dst) * 27) + str[len-1];
 }
}
```

Comment: Use of `strncpy()` is almost always wrong. also: it is `strncpy(dst,src,len)` so you appear to have the 1st and 2nd argument swapped. And dst points nowhere.

Comment: @wildplasser could you please elaborate more on why strncpy() is almost always wrong?

Comment: 1) if `arg3 <= strlen(arg2)` the resulting string will **not be nul-terminatrd**. 2) if  `arg3 > strlen(arg2)`, the remainder of the result is padded with NULs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> " error: passing argument 1 of 'strncpy' discards 'const' qualifier
>   from pointer target type"

This error results from the fact that first argument taken by strncpy is of type `char*` but you are passing `const char*`. Strncpy prototype is

```
char * strncpy ( char * destination, const char * source, size_t num );
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

First pointer is a pointer to the destination, not to the source.

Comment: thanks I updated OP, but now I get a seg fault for some reason

Comment: @Dad please show us actual code that segfaults as it is now, you should do it in separate question

Comment: The code on the op is the code that segfaults, and i don't want to spam, do you think it's valid to make another question on this?

Comment: use debugger and step into code, you should find a line that segfaults and cause of null pointer